# Extra < using auto complete in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I installed the All Autocomplete package in my Sublime Text 2 editor and everything works fine except when I type "`<div"` or something similar, the auto-complete box pops up, I select the one I want and hit enter and it adds "`<<div></div>`" with an extra "<" in the front of my tag. I have to go back and delete the extra "<" every time...(!)

I can't seem to resolve this issue. If I use the command CTRL+Space, the box pops up and I can select the tag I want and it does not include the extra tag but that messes with my flow.

Has anyone out there experienced this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just installed the package and it seems to work fine for me.

I type `<div` and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it completes correctly.

The only thing I can think of is that the AllAutocomplete package is conflicting with another package/plugin you may have installed.

Comment: I went in and uninstalled all packages related to HTML and now it seems to work fine. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with Zen Coding. [See here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4807).

Unfortunately I tried all suggestions there, including peruvianidol's 'Packages/HTML/html_completions.py' solution, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: No luck here either. I don't even have Zen Coding installed, and I have this issue. And it happens to _every_ type of autocomplete scenario, no matter the syntax or plugin. I even thought there might be something bound to the `tab` key, and so, with FindKeyConflicts, listed all the packages that respond to `tab` and disabled each one. Still no luck. Ugh---k, enough of this distraction; back to work.